# replacement in a file only in a fixed line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a shell script  in which I will read a file and will modify it.
there will be occurrence of some string  "ABC_1"  in multiple lines.
I need to replace it with "XYZ_1"  only when there is "OPQ_3" also present in the line else there should be no modification in the line.
please help how can I do replacement if I read a file liken by line.

```
for FILE in $FILES 
 do
   echo $FILE
   while read line
   do 
    if grep -n "OPQ_3" $line
      then

      sed -i 's/ABC_1/XYZ_2/'
    fi

   done  < $FILE
 done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -i '/OPQ_3\|OPQ_4/s/ABC_1/XYZ_2/' file
```

Comment: How can be a OR condition put here. for example if I have two  lines to be modified one with OPQ_3 and one with OPQ_4 ?

Comment: Thanks Anubhava .. this solution was helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Anubhava has the better answer. Here's how you'd write it in bash

```
for file in $FILES; do
    echo "$file"
    tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    while IFS= read -r line; do 
        [[ $line == *OPQ_3* ]] && line=${line/ABC_1/XYZ_2/}
        echo "$line"
    done < "$file" > "$tmpfile"
    mv "$tmpfile" "$file"
 done
```

Note `IFS= read -r line` is the only way to read a line from stdin *exactly*, without losing any whitespace or special characters.